# generalized ordered logit in R or python

Tags: python, r, logistic-regression

I would like to fit a generalized ordered logit model to some data I have. I first tried to use the ordered logit model using the MASS package from R, but it seems that the proportional odds assumption is violated by the data. Indeed, not all independent variables do exert the same effect across all categories of the dependent variable. Hence I am a bit blocked. I say that I could use the generalized ordered logit model instead, but could not find how to use it. Indeed, I can not find any package on either R or python that coud help me on that.

If someone has any hints on packages I could use, it would be of great help!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try the `oglmx` package. In [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oglmx/vignettes/oglmxVignette.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjM0IugmsXXAhVD1RoKHeVhDnEQFggqMAA&usg=AOvVaw1xBnK6C6o6Zs6UzM2LfLKy) link there is the vignette for that package.

For those who are interested in the method itself, [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292343504_Understanding_and_interpreting_generalized_ordered_logit_models) is some talk about that.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The reason why I was not sure about this 'oglmx' package, is that from my understanding its says 'generalized' because it overcome the issue of biais introduced by heteroskadicity in non-linear models. Hence,not to overcome the issue of parallel assumption. If I am wrong, I would be happy to know it :). This paper is given mroe details about the package through a nice example https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oglmx/vignettes/oglmxVignette.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'VGAM' package. There is a function called vglm.
example: vglm(Var2~factor(Var1),cumulative(parallel = F),data) generalized order model
cumulative(parallel=T) will perform a proportional odds model.
parallel=F is the default.